# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\text{d}x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration

Evaluate :
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\text{d}x}$$

Comment: How many weird integrals and sums have you posted now with absolutely no context or thought of your own?

Comment: @Ryan: if I understand mrf correctly, when you post one of these integrals, perhaps you may want to add a brief description of how you may have tried doing it, or how you think it may need to be done.  That said, I do not want to discourage your postings, as we have been able to learn some techniques for these problems.

Comment: It's hard for me to refrain myself from upvoting the question since I only focus on the problem itself (+1). On the other hand, I understand people that ask for more details because your question might be wrongly understood.

Comment: maple12 couldn't get closed form, numerically it's -0.34657...

Comment: @coffeemath: this seems like $-\ln 2 / 2$

Comment: @Chris'ssister Yes, looks like its $-ln(2)/2$ to a lot of decimal places. Not that strange maple didn't do it symbolically, I've seen it miss on other integrals known to have relatively simple expressions in closed form.

Comment: Anyone got a method?

Comment: I think your problem are also from my friend tian_275461 :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513413/show-that-int-0-infty-frac-cosat-cosbtt-ln-fracba). Here is a closed form solution of the integral

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\text{d}x} = -\frac{\ln(2)}{2}. $$

Here is the technique, consider the integral

$$ F(s) =  \int_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-sx}\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\text{d}x},  $$

which implies

$$ F''(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty }{e^{-sx}\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\text{d}x}. $$

The last integral is the Laplace transform of the function

$$  \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2}  $$

and equals

$$ F''(s) = \frac{1}{4}\,\psi' \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,s \right) -\frac{1}{2s}. $$

Now, you need to integrate the last equation twice and determine the two constants of integrations, then take the limit as $s\to 0$ to get the result.

Comment: Interesting method, I use trying to solve this yesterday, by $\psi$ do you mean $\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma '(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal  :Thx for your nice method! I struggled for few days and find a ugly solution...:)

Comment: Can you show how to get that two constants plz? :)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: brilliant! (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Thank you.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I think that Laplace point is a tricky one :+)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: you do have some explaining to do.  If I do as you say explicitly, I get $(1/2)\log{\pi}$, which is wrong.  The problem lies in the fact that $F'(0)$ is not finite.  Can you please let me know if you have seen this or have you seen something else?

Answer (score 12):

\begin{align}
?
&\equiv
{1 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{x - \sinh\left(x\right) \over x^{2}\sinh\left(x\right)}\,{\rm d}x
=
{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}2\pi{\rm i}
\lim_{x \to {\rm i}\,n\,\pi}
{\left\lbrack x - \sinh\left(x\right)\right\rbrack\left(x - {\rm i}n\pi\right)
 \over
 x^{2}\sinh\left(x\right)}
\\[3mm]&=
{\rm i}\,{\pi \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{{\rm i}n\pi \over \left({\rm i}n\pi\right)^{2}}\,\lim_{x \to {\rm i}\,n\,\pi}
{x - {\rm i}n\pi \over \sinh\left(x\right)}
=
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{1 \over n}\,{1 \over \cosh\left({\rm i}n\pi\right)}
=
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{1 \over n}\,{1 \over \cos\left(\pi n\right)}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\left(-1\right)^{n} \over n}
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}x
\left\lbrack
{{\rm d} \over {\rm d}x}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n} \over n}
\right\rbrack
=
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\rm d}x\,
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{n - 1}
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{-1 \over 1 - \left(-x\right)}\,{\rm d}x
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large -\,{1 \over 2}\,\ln\left(2\right)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

We also can use this way to calculate instead of using complex analysis or special functions. Noting that
$$ \int_0^\infty te^{-xt}dt=\frac{1}{x^2} $$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\text{d}x}\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\infty }{\left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\left(\int_0^\infty te^{-xt}\text{d}t\right)\text{d}x}\\
&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}t\left(\int_0^\infty \left( \frac{x}{{{\text{e}}^{x}}-{{\text{e}}^{-x}}}-\frac{1}{2} \right)e^{-xt}\text{d}t\right)\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}t\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{2xe^{-x}-1+e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}}e^{-xt}\text{d}x\right)\text{d}dt\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}t\left(\int_0^\infty(2xe^{-x}-1+e^{-2x})e^{-xt}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2nx}\text{d}x\right)\text{d}dt\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}t\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac1{2n+t}+\frac2{(2n+t+1)^2}+\frac1{2n+t+2}\right)\text{d}dt\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(1+n\ln n+\ln(n+\frac{1}{2})-(n+1)\ln(n+1)\right)\\
&=&-\lim_{n\to 0^+}\left(1+n\ln n+\ln(n+\frac{1}{2})-(n+1)\ln(n+1)\right)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1+n\ln n+\ln(n+\frac{1}{2})-(n+1)\ln(n+1)\right)\\
&=&-(1-\ln 2)+1-\frac32\ln 2\\
&=&-\frac12\ln 2.
\end{eqnarray}