# Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(at)-\cos(bt)}{t} =\ln\frac{b}{a}$

Tags: laplace-transform

It should be using Laplace transform.
I found similar problems already solved but I need this to be shown using Laplace transforms:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(at)-\cos(bt)}{t} = \ln\frac{b}{a}$$

Comment: Judging by the use of the word "need," this sounds like homework. If it is, please include whatever steps you have attempted so far. This helps any would-be answerers by not telling you something you already know (such dropping a hint you already figured out).

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/evaluate-int-0-infty-left-fracx-textex-texte-x/295326#295326). Here is a start. You can follow the steps

1) consider the integral

> $$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos at-\cos(bt)}{t}e^{-st}dt$$

2) find $F'(s)$

3) calculate the resulting integral.

I think you can finish it now?

Comment: Problem: $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos at}{t}e^{-st}\,dt$$ diverges due to the singularity in $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could we fix this by replacing $\cos(at)$ with $\cos(at)-1$? I haven't checked the details, but perhaps differentiation under the integral sign works then?

Comment: @DanielFischer And then the $1$s will cancel when we subtract, of course.

Comment: @Potato That would work. But why the detour, differentiating $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos at - \cos bt}{t}e^{-st}\,dt$$ directly would also work.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for the comment.