# How to approach/solve this integral?

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, contour-integration

Could somebody suggest how to approach or solve this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-a t}{2+t-2\sqrt{1+t}\over t^2}{\rm d\,}t,
$$
where $a>0$ ? It is not a homework. I tried to use residuum calculation but did not find a path encircling the pole of order 2 at zero that would became the real integral I need to calculate. Other option was to get rid of the double pole to become just a simple pole to be able to indent it (if necessary). So I integrated per partes using
$$
v'=1/t^2
$$
and
$$
u=e^{-a t}(2+t-2\sqrt{1+t})
$$

I indeed got a slightly different integral with just a simple pole at zero and another pole at -1 (and a branch cut):
$$
\int_{0}^\infty {e^{-a t}\over t}\left(-a(2+t-2\sqrt{1+t})+{\sqrt{1+t}-1\over\sqrt{1+t}}\right){\rm d\,}t.
$$
This is when I got stucked since I need to get a real integral from 0 to $\infty$ but the branch cut starts at -1 so my indentation plan failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start. Differentiating twice with respect to $a$ gives

> $$ \int_{0}^\infty e^{-a t}(2+t-2\sqrt{1+t}){\rm d\,}t.$$

Now, work out the integral and follow the technique used in this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552384/proving-of-integral-int-0-infty-frace-bx-e-axxdx-ln-left-fr/552468#552468).

Comment: Is it not just parts/substitution from here?

Comment: The Laplace transform can be done and yes, per partes follows and we got the result. Hats off to Mhenni Benghorbal for this elegant method. Almost feel ashamed that I did not find it by myself.

Comment: @leprotic: You are very welcome.