# A Mathematical Proof for an Improper Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I got the following solution for the integral $I$ from Wolfram and I have verified the solution numerically which seems to be correct! Does someone have an idea about the mathematical proof?

$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}sin(bx)}{x} dx = \arctan(\frac{b}{a})$

in which a and b are some positive constants.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it should be $\text{arctan}\left(\frac ba\right)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I cannot calculate the integral resulting from integration with respect to $b$, i.e. $\int \frac{b \sin(bx) - a \cos(bx)}{a^2+b^2} db$.

Comment: You applied the limits incorrectly.  It should be much simpler than that.  I think you forgot to set $x$ to zero.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax} \cos(bx) \, dx$, which is easily worked out.  Then integrate with respect to $b$.  Use $b=0$ to establish the integration constant.  Wave your hands to explain the validity of exchanging the two integrals (or cite Fubini's Theorem).

Comment: You beat me to it (I was going to provide more details …) But more to the point, the path to discovering this proof involves differentiating the original integral with respect to $a$ in order to get rid of the bothersome $x$ in the denominator. Then realize that it is better to do this argument backwards because Fubini is easier to justify than differentiating under the integral sign.

Comment: Yes, I must admit that I did it be first differentiating.  And I'm sure I had seen the trick used somewhere else, and was dragging up stuff from my memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps

i) Differentiate $I$ w.r.t. $a$.

ii) evaluate the integral $I_a$.

iii) integrate with respect with $a$ and note that $\lim_{a\to \infty} I =0. $

Here is a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552384/proving-of-integral-int-0-infty-frace-bx-e-axxdx-ln-left-fr/552468#552468).

Answer (score 0):

It might be straightforward to use the technique of Laplace transform, particularly from [Laplace transform of the product of two functions](https://ijpam.uniud.it/online_issue/202044/71%20RamiAlahmad.pdf).

\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-sx}\sin(bx)}{x}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left[\frac1x\right](\xi)\mathcal{L}\left[\sin(bx)\right](s+\xi)\mathrm d\xi\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}1(\xi)\frac{b}{(s+\xi)^2+b^2}\mathrm d\xi\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\frac{s}{b})\\&=\arctan(\frac{b}{s}).
\end{align}