# Improper integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

For $a>b>0$, calculate
   $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x}\ dx$$

**My try** : By **Taylor series**, $$\int\ \frac{e^{-ax} - e^{-bx}}{x} \ dx=  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{[\ (-a)^n -(-b)^n\ ]}{n}\frac{x^n}{n!} +C $$

Note that from **ratio test**, this series **converges absolutely** for $x\in [0,\infty)$. So give me a hint. Thanks

**Seocond Try** : Recall $$ \Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty s^{t-1}e^{-s}\ ds\ (t>0)$$

So $$\Gamma(t) = a^t \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-as}}{s^{1-t}}\ ds$$

So integral we want to calculate is $$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\ [a^{-t} - b^{-t}]\ \Gamma(t) $$ Right ?

**See** I found the following article [proving of Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bx}-e^{-ax}}{x}dx = \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552384/proving-of-integral-int-0-infty-frace-bx-e-axxdx-ln-left-fr?rq=1)

Comment: This is a special case of Frullani integrals. For statement, generalizations and proofs, look at answers of this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61828/59379),

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-bx}}{x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b}e^{-rx}dr\,dx
 = \int_{a}^{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-rx}dxdr = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dr}{r}
$$

Comment: nicely done... +1

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved by differentiating under the integral sign.
Writing $$ I(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{x} dx$$
We immediately see that $$ \frac{dI}{dt} = -\int_0^\infty e^{-tx} dx $$
which equals $\frac{-1}{a}$.
So $$I = -\log\ {t} + C $$
And the given integral is therefore,
$$-\log\ a - (-\log\ b) = \log\ (\frac{b}{a})$$

Comment: This integral $I(t)$  is note exist, since it's diverges at $0$, since $\frac{e^{-tx}}{x} \sim \frac{1}{x}$ when $x \to 0$.