# Integral of triangular relation

Tags: integration

I think this question would be with complicated methods in singularity or other kind of methods.
I need to solve the integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx$$
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show how have you tried

Comment: using Laplace transforms: $\log(|b/a|)$

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552384) question.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Either use the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities) for $\cos A\pm\cos B$, which will ultimately result in an expression

similar to that of [Dirichlet's integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral), or employ a trick similar to [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html), namely by

noticing that $~\dfrac{\cos ax-\cos bx}x~=~\displaystyle\int_a^b\sin(tx)~dt,~$ and then switch the order of integration

via [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem).

Comment: Have you considered convergence of the resulting integral?

Comment: @RonGordon: Just because it [doesn't converge](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309), doesn't mean that it cannot be [evaluated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generality_of_algebra)... ;-$)$

Comment: Yes, but it does mean you need to reconsider quoting Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @RonGordon: Or we could simply use it to justify the switch for a non-imaginary exponential integrand, and then mischievously and underhandedly generalize the real result for complex values of the exponent, via the Hand-Waving Theorem.