# Question related to Laplace transformation and it's final value theorem.

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

I have been solving problems related to Laplace transformation involving the initial/final value theorem but got stuck at a step. The question is as follows:

Given $L{[\int^{\infty}_{t}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}}dx](s)=sf(s)$,for s>0. Then find $f(s)$ using the final value theorem.

Here are the steps which followed:

$L[f(t)]=\int^{\infty}_{0}f(t)e^{-st}dt$ where $f(t)=\int^{\infty}_{t}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$
$L[f(t)]=\int^{\infty}_{0}[\int^{\infty}_{t}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx]e^{-st}dt$
Using the change of order of integral, we can write:
$L[f(t)]=\int^{\infty}_{0}[\int^{x}_{0} e^{-st}dx]\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dt$
$L[f(t)]=\frac{-1}{s}\int^{\infty}_{0}[e^{-sx}-1]\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$
$L[f(t)]=\frac{-1}{s}\int^{\infty}_{0}[\frac{e^{-x(s+1)}}{x}-\frac{e^{-x}}{x}]dx$

I am not able to perform the Laplace transformation on the above last expression as it is not integrable. The final value theorem states the if we know Laplace transform$f(s)$ of any function $f(t)$ then we can find $f(\infty)$ by solving, $$f(\infty)=\lim_{s\to 0} s.f(s)$$ But I have no idea how I can use this theorem to find $f(s)$.

Am I solving it wrongly? Should I approach in a different way? What can I do to find $f(s)$?
Please clarify my doubts.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approch leads to the final answer.
After your last step, apply [Proof of Frullani's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem),
$$\int_0^{+\infty}  {\frac{{f\left( {ax} \right) - f\left( {bx} \right)}}
{x}}\,dx  = f\left( 0 \right) {\ln\left( \frac{b}
{a}\right)} $$
with $f(x)=e^{-x}$, $a=s+1$, $b=1$. It follows that
$$L\left[\int^{\infty}_{t}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx\right](s)=\frac{\ln(s+1)}{s}.$$
However I don't know how to use the [Final Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) in order to get the same answer. Maybe you can take a look at this answer [Proving of Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bx}-e^{-ax}}{x}dx = \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552384/proving-of-integral-int-0-infty-frace-bx-e-axxdx-ln-left-fr/552468#552468) where the Frullani's theorem is proved by using the Laplace transform.

Comment: Thanks! I have got the answer from your hint but what is the point of mentioning the final value theorem then?

Comment: @UjjawalM. Using your approach we find the result in that way. I don't know how we can use the final value theorem the get the same answer.

Comment: @UjjawalM. Where does this exercise come from? Are you sure that the statement is correct?

Comment: It's just a question asked in my classwork which I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Have you a similar example where the use of the Final VALUE Theorem gives a FUNCTION?

Comment: @No I have got no example, they just briefed the final value theorem and asked the question. I have solved problem-related to the final/initial theorem where we just have to find the $f(0)$ and &f(\infty)&. But not anything like this. I have been figuring it out from last day. Btw, Is my approach correct?

Comment: @UjjawalM. Yes, your approach is correct. See also my edit.

Comment: @UjjawalM. Anyway, I hope that my amswer was useful.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119156/discussion-between-ujjawal-m-and-robert-z).