# Evaluate the integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: calculus

(trying to understand the substitution for Feynman's method for this... I've seen a few examples of exactly this problem, but I can't seem to get the mechanics of it:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}\mathrm{d}y$$

1. splits to $\int \frac{e^{-ay}}{y}\mathrm{d}y - \int \frac{e^{-by}}{y}\mathrm{d}y$ ?
2. add some function?

Comment: For your interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral

Comment: You can't split the improper integral like what you did for (1.) because there is a pole at $y=0$. The functions $\frac{e^{-ay}}{y}$ and $\frac{e^{-by}}{y}$ aren't improperly integrable over any domain containing a neighborhood of $y=0$.

Comment: ...or simply integrating by part:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}dy=\ln y\,(e^{-ay}-e^{-by})\Big|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty\ln y\,(ae^{-ay}-be^{-by})dy$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\Big(\ln \frac{t}{a}-\ln \frac{t}{b}\Big)e^{-t}dt=\ln\frac{b}{a}$$

Comment: This might be useful: [Proving of Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-bx}-e^{-ax}}{x}dx = \ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552384).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{e^{-ay} - e^{-by}}{y} = \int_{a}^{b} \exp(-yz) \, dz$$ so we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} \exp(-yz) \, dz \, dy \overset{\text{Fubini}}{=} \int_{a}^{b} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-yz) \, dy \, dz $$ $$= \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{y} \, dy = \ln(b/a)$$ The use of Fubini's theorem is justified since the function of interest is nonnegative everywhere (and hence [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli%27s_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_functions) applies).

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be the original integral. To use Feynman's Method, we can use the Laplace Transformation

$$F\left(s\right)\ =\ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}e^{-sy}dy,$$

where $s+a,s+b > 0$. Taking $\dfrac{d}{ds}$ on both sides, we get

$$F'(s) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}e^{-sy}dy = -\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(e^{-ay}-e^{-by}\right)e^{-sy}dy = \frac{a-b}{s^{2}+\left(a+b\right)s+ab}.$$

Integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ on both sides with respect to $s$, we apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}F'\left(s\right)ds\ =\ F\left(\infty\right)-F\left(0\right)\ =\ 0\ -\ I\ =-I.$$

We can also do some grunt work and get

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}F'\left(s\right)ds\ =\ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a-b}{s^{2}+\left(a+b\right)s+ab}ds\ =\ \ln\left(a\right)-\ln\left(b\right).$$

By the transitive property, we get

$$-I = \ln\left(a\right)-\ln\left(b\right).$$

Therefore, the integral $I$ is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ay}-e^{-by}}{y}dy = \ln\left(b\right) - \ln\left(a\right).$$

Comment: (Technically I'm not "plugging in $\infty$," I'm taking the limit as some variable approaches it. I'm just abusing notations.)