# How to calculate the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{\mathrm{e}^x-\mathrm{e}^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

How to calculate the improper integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{\mathrm{e}^x-\mathrm{e}^{-x}}-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}$$
Do you have same idea?

Comment: Are you allowed to use complex numbers?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/evaluate-int-0-infty-left-fracx-textex-texte-x/295326#295326) is exactly the same problem.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thank you very much!

Comment: @DaoyiPeng: You are very welcome.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Of course, How to solve it?

Comment: @DaoyiPeng I was wondering about the substitution $z=e^{ix}$, the first term of the integral can be expressed as a hyperbolic sine function, but in any case you already have a lint to the same question. :)