# Help in evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 \sin x \cos^2 x}{x e^{x \sqrt{3}}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help in evaluating $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{2 \sin x \cos^2 x}{x e^{x \sqrt{3}}}$

The original question: Evaluate $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{- x \sqrt 3}}{x} (1 - \sin x)(1 + 2 \sin x - \cos 2x)$

Using $\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$ and $1 - \sin^2 x = \cos^2 x$ I was able to get it into the above form. However, I do not know how to proceed. I would  like some guidance rather than a full answer, please.

Comment: The integral is non-elementary, so you can't evaluate it completely.  Instead, you get error integrals.

Comment: Is there a closed form for the definite integral?

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%282+sin%28x%29+cos%28x%29+cos%28x%29%29%2F%28x+E%5E%28xsqrt%283%29%29%29+dx for the indefinite integral.

Comment: Is the original integral expressible in closed form? What is the motivation for this question? Contour integration? Transformations? ...

Comment: Check this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/evaluate-int-0-infty-left-fracx-textex-texte-x/295326#295326).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider the Laplace transform

$$F(p)=\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \cos^2{x} \, e^{-p x}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}F'(p) &= -\int_0^{\infty} dx \, \sin{x} \cos^2{x} \, e^{-p x}\\ &= -\frac14 \int_0^{\infty} dx \,(\sin{3 x}+\sin{x}) e^{-p x}\\ &= -\frac14 \left (\frac{3}{p^2+9}+\frac1{p^2+1} \right )\end{align}$$

Thus

$$F(p) = -\frac14 \left (\arctan{\frac{p}{3}}+\arctan{p} \right ) +C$$

The integration constant is

$$\begin{align}C &= \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \cos^2{x}\\ &= \frac14 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin{3 x}}{x} + \frac14 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \\ &= \frac14 \left ( \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right )\\ &= \frac{\pi}{4}\end{align}$$

so that

$$F(p) = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac14 \left (\arctan{\frac{p}{3}}+\arctan{p}  \right ) $$

and your answer is $2 F(\sqrt{3})$ (which accounts for the factor of two in the original integral):

$$\begin{align}2 F(\sqrt{3}) &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac12 \left (\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}+\arctan{\sqrt{3}}  \right )\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac12 \left (\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi}{3} \right ) \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{2\sin\pars{x}\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over x \expo{x\root{3}}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{3}}\,
{\sin\pars{x} + \sin\pars{x}\cos\pars{2x} \over x }\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{3}}\,
{\sin\pars{x} + \bracks{\sin\pars{x + 2x} + \sin\pars{x - 2x}}/2 \over x }\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x\root{3}}\,
{\sin\pars{3x} + \sin\pars{x} \over x }\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\color{#c00000}{\half\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{\expo{-\root{3}x/3} + \expo{-\root{3}x}}\,
{\sin\pars{x} \over x }\,\dd x}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> With $\mu > 0$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\mu x}\,{\sin\pars{x} \over x }\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\mu x}\,\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd k\,\dd x
> =\half\int_{-1}^{1}\dd k\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{\ic k - \mu}x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{-1}^{1}{-1 \over \ic k - \mu}\,\dd k
> =\half\int_{-1}^{1}{\ic k + \mu \over k^{2} + \mu^{2}}\,\dd k
> =\int_{0}^{1}{\mu \over k^{2} + \mu^{2}}\,\dd k
> =\color{#00f}{\arctan\pars{1 \over \mu}}
> \end{align}

By replacing this result in $\pars{1}$ we find:
\begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{2\sin\pars{x}\cos^{2}\pars{x} \over x \expo{x\root{3}}}\,\dd x}
=\half\bracks{\arctan\pars{\root{3}} + \arctan\pars{\root{3} \over 3}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\pars{{\pi \over 3} + {\pi \over 6}}
= \color{#00f}{\large{\pi \over 4}} \approx 0.7854
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer does not give the same solution as Ron Gordon's.

Comment: @MichaelT I'm checking right now. $\tt @RonGordon$ solution is the correct one $\left(~{\pi \over 4}~\right)$.

Comment: @MichaelT An infamous minus sign (-) must be a nice (+) sign. Now, it's $0$ k. Thanks.